# The average weight of a cycle in graph

Tags: algorithms, graphs

I have a weighed undirected graph. How is possible find the minimum average cycle weight. The average weight of a cycle is the weight of this cycle divided by the number of edges in it. And I must return the answer up to $\varepsilon$, where $\varepsilon$ is required precision.

Comment: Is $\varepsilon$ an additive or a multiplicative factor?

Comment: This value $\varepsilon$ means how many digits after the floating point should be considered significant.

Comment: The problem can be solved in polynomial time, see [this paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1572528608000662) for the appropriate references.